# URLResourceValues not working for renaming a file

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsfilemanager

I have to rename some files in a directory in the Documents directory. I'm trying with URLResourceValues:

```
let fileURLs = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: directory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
fileURLS.forEach { fileURL in
    // calculate newFileName
    var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
    resourceValues.name = newFilename
    var mutableFileURL = fileURL
    try! mutableFileURL.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
}
```

After setting `resourceValues.name` I see this in the console...

```
key NSMutableString "NSURLNameKey"  0x00000001e7a8a368
value   NSString    "newName.jpg"   0x0000000283f61fe0
```

So that part is working. The `try!` completes without crashing so there were no errors thrown. But `mutableFileURL` is unchanged. It's got the old name, not the new name.

I see in the docs that setting read-only properties or setting properties not supported will be ignored and will not throw an error. But in my research I see this approach used commonly for renaming files. And I don't think it's a write access thing because if I use the old way it works fine:

```
try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL, to: newFileURL)
```

What could I be missing here?

P.S. app targets iOS 14, running on a real device running iOS 16.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown how you *know* things didn't work. But you say:

> But `mutableFileURL` is unchanged

Your code isn't *supposed* to change `mutableFileURL`. If you're looking at `mutableFileURL` to see what happened, that's the problem.

The URL here is just a *pointer* to the file on disk. That's the whole point of the `setResourceValues` approach. Your code changes the name of the file *on disk* (and `mutableFileURL`, the pointer, is now invalid and should just be thrown away).

If you *re-fetch the contents of the documents directory,* you'll see that your code worked just fine.

Complete example, showing both what I think *you* are doing and how to do this *correctly:*

```
// --- create the file ---
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try fm.url(
    for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,
    appropriateFor: nil, create: false
)

let newurl = docsurl.appending(path: "howdy.txt")
try "howdy".write(to: newurl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

let arr = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(
    at: docsurl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
)
arr.forEach { print($0.lastPathComponent) }
// howdy.txt

// --- rename the file ---
var values = URLResourceValues()
values.name = "hello.txt"
var mutableurl = newurl
try mutableurl.setResourceValues(values)

// --- how did we do? this is _not_ the way:
print(mutableurl)
// file:///.../Documents/howdy.txt

// --- how did we do? this _is_ the way
let arr2 = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(
    at: docsurl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
)
arr2.forEach { print($0.lastPathComponent) }
// hello.txt
```